# Please check jQuery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will be very grateful is sb tells me whether code below has a correct syntax.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
  var sliderHeight = $(window).height() - $('.slider').position().top;
  $('.slider').css({'height': sliderHeight});
  $('.landing-title').css({'top': $('.slider').height() / 2 - $('.landing-title').height() / 2}) ;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    sliderHeight = $(window).height() - $('.slider').position().top;
    $('.slider').css({'height': sliderHeight }); 
    $('.landing-title').css({'top': $('.slider').height() / 2 - $('.landing-title').height() / 2});
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Do you get error messages? Why are you concerned?

Comment: JS is sth new to me and I would like to have 100% certainity. How can iI test it? It works anyway

Comment: You could test it on your computer by saving it as a file (with header, links to jQuery and body), you can put it up on your server, you can create a fiddle...

Comment: You take the code, put it on a page, load the page and look at the browser console whether it throws any error. Or open the console directly and paste the code. In your case: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you and help yourself.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to be __specific programming problems__ expressed _clearly_. Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's more about codereview than a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is syntactically wrong as you you have mixed up the function ending braces.
Below is the syntactically manipulated code. Hope you find that helpful.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var sliderHeight = $(window).height()-$('.slider').position().top;
    $('.slider').css({ 'height': sliderHeight });
    $('.landing-title').css({ 'top': $('.slider').height()/2 - $('.landing-title').height()/2 }) ;
});

$(window).resize(function(){ sliderHeight = $(window).height()-$('.slider').position().top;
    $('.slider').css({ 'height': sliderHeight });
    $('.landing-title').css({ 'top': $('.slider').height()/2 - $('.landing-title').height()/2 }) ; 
});
```

Comment: but now it does not work. It worked when I put window.resize inside document.ready...

Comment: Please share the link of HTML file and I will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

the last bracket can be wrong

It can be like below
});